# jmeter.log file is not created in non GUI mode

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-logging

Im running my jmeter script using a SH file having below commands,

```
#! /bin/sh
JMETER_HOME=/jmeter/DummyTest/Jmeter4/apache-jmeter-4.0
#PATH=$PATH:JMETER_HOME/bin
#export PATH
echo $PATH
cd $1
echo current dir is `pwd`
echo "=== START OF  run-load-atcom_scripts.sh SCRIPT ==="
$JMETER_HOME/bin/jmeter.sh -n -t /jmeter/DummyTest/TrialScript1.jmx
```

while running im getting below error

```
Uncaught Exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed calling setupTest. See log file for details.
```

In this case im not getting jmeter.log file creating or updating in jmeter bin folder.

Can anyone help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

Got to fix this ,i have given the command -j /path/to/logfile/logfile.log

which works.

Apart from this anyways if anyone comes up with any solution(rather using -j ,automatically in bin folder ) would be helpful for everyone